# WordPress text background disappears when text wraps

Tags: wordpress, colors, background, word-wrap

I have the problem that when I view my site on mobile devices or if I manually resize my viewing window to a point where the text begins to wrap, the white area behind my text disappears. This whould not be a big problem in mormal circumstances but for me it's a problem because I have a dark background image and this makes it impossible to read the text once this happens. I tried to solve the problem by disabling responsiveness but this did not solve the problem.

Here is my the website: me-afrika.de

Does anyone have any ideas how I can overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white background is being applied to the ".container" element only when the window is at least 1024px wide.

At smaller sizes it's trying to load a background image that doesn't exist (http://www.me-afrika.de/wp-content/themes/musicplus/images/content/main-n.png).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I truly appreciate it... That's exactly where the problem was - the images were declared in mobile.css and tablet.css but were non-existent in the ../images/content folder. This was probably an oversight by the theme designers. All I had to do was find another theme from the same theme company which contained those three files (main-n.png, bottom-n.png and top-n.png), edit the colours to correspond with my theme, and that solved the problem.